# C++ template method and obtaining result - design

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've such an interface class:

```
class MyInterface
{
  public:
    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
    virtual Result GetResult() = 0;
};
```

and simple abstract method, which realizes template pattern:

```
class Abstract: public MyInterface
{
  public:
    void DoStuff()
    {
      DoAFoo();
      BakeAPie();
      PrepareResult();  
    }

    virtual DoAFoo() = 0;
    virtual BakeAPie() = 0;
    virtual PrepareResult() = 0;  
};
```

And here comes my question. The method GetResult() should be implemented by every concrete implementation of Abstract? There would be a lot of such subclasses.

Or it should be handled in the Abstract class? Like this:

```
class Abstract: public MyInterface
{
  public:
    ....
    GetResult()
    {
      return m_result;
    }

  private:
    Result m_result;
}
```

But how can I ensure, that Abstract subclasses will fill m_result within PrepareResult()?

Comment: Why should `Abstract` implement *any* methods of `MyInterface`?

Comment: To avoid repeting exactly the same implementation of DoStuff() in a lot of concrete implementations. I would like also to avoid repeting GetResult(), but I'm not convinced if it would be a good practice here.

Comment: What's the relationship between `Abstract` and `MyInterface`?

Comment: But there seems to be no connection between `MyInterface` and `Abstract`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you. I forgot about an inheritance ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask yourself this question: "Is storing the result in a member and returning that member from `GetResult()` the only sane implementation of `GetResult()`? Some generally possible alternatives could be:

- Compute the result on demand each time `GetResult()` is called.
- Caching more than one result somewhere and returning the proper one from `GetResult()` based on circumstances.
- Something else...?

Without knowing your exact problem, we cannot answer this, only you can.

If you arrive at the conclusion that yes, storing a single result in a member and returning it is the only sane approach, you can go ahead and implement `GetResult()` in `Abstract`, because then everybody else would be doing the exact same thing anyway. And to guarantee correct behaviour of `PrepareResult()`, you can change the interface as follows:

```
class Abstract: public MyInterface
{
  public:
    void DoStuff()
    {
      DoAFoo();
      BakeAPie();
      m_result = PrepareResult();  
    }

    virtual void DoAFoo() = 0;
    virtual void BakeAPie() = 0;
    virtual Result PrepareResult() = 0;

    virtual Result GetResult()
    { return m_result; }

  private:
    Result m_result;
};
```

Note that I'd suggest you mark `GetResult()` as `const` in `MyInterface` (and so in `Abstract` as well). It makes sense for this to be a `const` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement GetResult in MyInterface, add a Result property in this class and its constructors.

Or you should delete this function in the interface and implement it in a subclass. Because if the interface doesn't hold this property, it may means that the interface knows too much.

Comment: On the other hand, there's also a value to having interface classes with inline and pure-virtual functions only (no data).

Comment: In my humble opinion, the interface should be... an interface. Without any properties.